# What does "-" mean in haml?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I am pretty new to web-design and working on some code that part of it is like this:

```
  .row-fluid
    - if(params[:offset].to_i>0)
      = link_to t('.previous'), reports_path(offset: give_previous_page(@offset, @limit)),
        { class: 'btn btn-small btn-primary'}
    - else
```

some of the things I understand so far, for example Ok this is a Rail code, instead of `ERB` we have used `HAML` syntax and there some twitter bootstrap classes like those `.row-fluid` and `btn-primary` in it too, but the part that I don' understand is that `"-"` that we see next to the lines with "`if`" an "`else`" . What are those and what do they do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In HAML under Rails, `-` means "this line is Ruby code; don't output its value".

By contrast `=` means "this line is Ruby code; output its value".